# How to use `debug.getinfo(f).nparams` in Lua C API?

Tags: lua

I learned that it is possible to find out how many arguments a function expects by using `debug.getinfo(f).nparams` in Lua.

Could someone please teach me how to do this in Lua C API before calling a function using `lua_pcall()`?

Here's my sample code for calling a Lua function.

```
void doFunction(lua_State *L, int argc, t_atom *argv)
{
    lua_getglobal(L, "require");
    lua_pushstring(L, "foo"); //require("foo")
    if (lua_pcall(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0))
    {
        error("error: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        return;
    }
    int top = lua_gettop(L);
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "test"); //find foo.test() function
    if (lua_type(L, -1) != LUA_TFUNCTION)
    {
        lua_pop(L, 2);
        return;
    }
    lua_newtable(L);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) //convert array to lua table
    {
        lua_pushinteger(L, static_cast<lua_Integer>(i + 1));
        if (argv[i].a_type == A_FLOAT)
            lua_pushnumber(L, static_cast<lua_Number>(argv[i].a_w.w_float));
        else if (argv[i].a_type == A_SYMBOL)
            lua_pushstring(L, argv[i].a_w.w_symbol->s_name);
        lua_settable(L, -3);
    }
    if (lua_pcall(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0)) //call foo.test() function
    {
        error("error: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        return;
    }
    if (lua_gettop(L) - top)
    {
        //do something with the returned value
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

This code is trying to `require` `foo`, and then call the `test` function, using the array of arguments provided to `doFunction`.

I learned that I can find out how many arguments a function expects by putting the following code properly somewhere:

```
 lua_Debug ar;
 lua_getinfo(L, ">u", &ar);
 printf("%d\n", ar.nparams);
```

However, I couldn't figure out where to put these lines to make my code work properly.

Can anyone please teach me how to do it?

---

**ADDED:**

I would like to call a function by passing either a table or parameter values depending on the number of arguments the function expects. For example, if the function is expecting one argument, I will pass a table to the function. But if the function is expecting multiple arguments, I would like to pass the values as multiple parameters. This is why I would need to use `debug.getinfo(f).nparams`.

Comment: @luther Thank you so much. Please see my edited post.

Comment: "*However, I couldn't figure out where to put these lines to make my code work properly.*" Where to put them in order to make your code work *how*? It's not really clear what your code is trying to accomplish and why you need to know the number of parameters for a function. Your function is calling a function by passing it a table containing values. Where is asking a question for the number of parameters supposed to fit in here? Are you trying instead to pass the array as actual parameters rather than a table?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I'm trying to pass the array as actual parameters rather than a table.

Comment: If you're going to put a bounty on your question, asking for answers to have more details, it might be a good idea to put all of your question *in your question*, rather than forcing someone to read through the comments to try to figure out what it is that you're *actually* looking for. And try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @NicolBolas I just did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_getinfo) describes how to get information about a function:

> To get information about a function you push it onto the stack and start the what string with the character '>'. (In that case, lua_getinfo pops the function from the top of the stack.) For instance, to know in which line a function f was defined, you can write the following code:
>
> ```
> lua_Debug ar;
> lua_getglobal(L, "f");  /* get global 'f' */
> lua_getinfo(L, ">S", &ar);
> printf("%d\n", ar.linedefined);
> ```

So the only thing you are missing is to push the function value you want to inspect to the top of the Lua stack.

To give you something to play with, here is the implementation of a C function that calls the function passed as first argument with the remaining arguments -- either as an array or as individual parameters, depending on the number of expected arguments:

```
 /* build instructions for `args.c` on Ubuntu Linux:
 * `gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/lua5.2 -fpic -shared -o args.so args.c`
 */
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>


/* copies a Lua stack interval into an array */
static void push_pack(lua_State* L, int first, int last) {
  int i;
  first = lua_absindex(L, first);
  last = lua_absindex(L, last);
  lua_createtable(L, last > first ? last - first : 0, 0);
  for (i = first; i <= last; ++i) {
    lua_pushvalue(L, i);
    lua_rawseti(L, -2, i-first+1);
  }
}


static int args(lua_State* L) {
  lua_Debug ar;
  /* first argument must be a function to call, rest are additional
   * args for this function */
  luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TFUNCTION);
  /* query number of expected arguments */
  lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
  lua_getinfo(L, ">u", &ar);
  if (ar.nparams > 1 || ar.isvararg) { /* pass as multiple args */
    lua_call(L, lua_gettop(L)-1, LUA_MULTRET);
    return lua_gettop(L);
  } else { /* create array and pass it as single arg */
    int top = lua_gettop(L);
    lua_pushvalue(L, 1); /* push function first */
    push_pack(L, 2, top); /* then argument array */
    lua_call(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET);
    return lua_gettop(L) - top;
  }
}


int luaopen_args(lua_State* L) {
  lua_pushcfunction(L, args);
  return 1;
}
```

Tested on Lua 5.2 with

```
#!/usr/bin/lua5.2

local args = require("args")

local function f(x, ...)
  print(">", x, ...)
  return 5, 6
end

local function g(x)
  print(">", x)
  for i,v in ipairs(x) do
    print("", i, v)
  end
  return 7, 8
end

local function h(x, y)
  print(">", x, y)
  return 9, 10
end


print(args(f, 1, 2, 3))
print(args(g, 1, 2, 3))
print(args(h, 1, 2, 3))
print(args(print, 1, 2, 3))
```